# 256-bit arithmetic in Clang (extended integers)

Tags: c, clang, x86-64, bigint, extint

I'm in the design phase of a project that needs to do a lot of simple 256-bit integer arithmetic (add, sub, mul, div only) and need something that is reasonably well optimised for these four operations.

I'm already familiar with GMP, NTL and most of the other heavyweight bignum implementations. However, the overhead of these implementations is pushing me towards doing my own low-level implementation - which I *really* don't want to do; this stuff is notoriously hard to get right.

In my research I noticed the new extended integer types in Clang - I am a gcc user - and I was wondering if anyone has any experience of the extended integers in real-life, in-anger implementations? Are they optimised for the "obvious" bit sizes (256, 512, etc)?

I'm working in C on x-64 under linux (currently Ubuntu, though open to other distributions if necessary). I mostly use gcc for production work.

Edited to add:
@phuclv identified a previous answer [C++ 128/256-bit fixed size integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242819/c-128-256-bit-fixed-size-integer-types). (Thanks @phuclv.) This q/a focuses on c++ support; I was hoping to identify whether anyone had any specific experience with the new Clang types.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! And congratulations for an interesting question as your first post! Unfortunately, can only give you this [blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2020/04/the-new-clang-extint-feature-provides.html)

Comment: use some libraries like boost, https://github.com/calccrypto/uint256_t or https://www.ttmath.org/ instead. [C++ 128/256-bit fixed size integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5242819/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ 128/256-bit fixed size integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242819/c-128-256-bit-fixed-size-integer-types)

Comment: Hi @phuclv. Thanks for the link to the previous question/answer. I'm familiar with the boost stuff and various other c++ things mentioned in the answers- and may well have to go there in the end :( !
Thank you for the calccrypto link though - I hadn't seen that one before.
I was, though, hoping to utilise something that was native, and hence more likely to be space and speed efficient, hence the question as to whether anyone had any experience with the new types in Clang.

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta. It was that blog that started me down this path!!!

Comment: Do you need portability to GCC?  Your question was only tagged with clang and clang-llvm, where clang's new extension will give you very good inlined asm.  Fully unrolled, so don't use it for *huge* integers, but 256-bit = 4x 64 is fine especially for add/sub. 512-bit is a bit bulky for mul and especially div I'd assume.  IDK if division looks for special cases of the divisor being only 1 limb, try it on https://godbolt.org/ or single-step through the asm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like division with these types is not currently supported beyond 128 bits.

As of 2 August 2020, using clang [trunk](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/4ffa6a27aca17fe88fa6bdd605b198df6632a570) on godbolt, compiling the following code for x86-64

```
typedef unsigned _ExtInt(256) uint256;

uint256 div(uint256 a, uint256 b) {
    return a/b;
}
```

fails with the error message

```
fatal error: error in backend: Unsupported library call operation!
```

[Try it](https://godbolt.org/z/8nKGdn)

The same thing happens with `_ExtInt(129)` and everything larger that I tried.  `_ExtInt(128)` and smaller seem to work, though they call the internal library function `__udivti3` instead of inlining.

It has been reported as [LLVM bug 45649](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45649).  There is some discussion on that page, but the upshot seems to be that they do not really want to write a full arbitrary-precision divide instruction.

Addition, subtraction and multiplication do work with `_ExtInt(256)` on this version.

Comment: `__udivti3` is large (branching on special cases because the general case is hard); you generally wouldn't want to inline it.  (Except maybe for the special case where the divisor is known to fit in 64 bits so a chain of `div` instructions can work.)  Division is also slow enough that call/ret overhead is minor.  (related: [Why is \_\_int128\_t faster than long long on x86-64 GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63029428) points out that signed __int128 is even worse.)

Comment: Well, I guess that answers my question!

Comment: @NateEldredge what about additions or bitwise operators?

Comment: @user2284570: I mentioned already that addition, subtraction and multiplication work, and bitwise operations also work fine as far as I can tell.  They are much easier so you would expect they'd be the most likely to be supported.

Comment: So, the problem is just using signed division?

Comment: @user2284570: Both signed and unsigned division seem to be unsupported.

Comment: And modulus. Also I was expecting to be able to get cutting edge avx512 code with multiplication, but it appears the implementation is very poor performance.

Comment: @user2284570: SIMD is hard to use for extended-precision; you need the code using it to be aware of deferring renormalization across a few operations. [Can long integer routines benefit from SSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8866973)   And AVX-512 only gives you at most 64x64 => 64-bit multiply (in 8 chunks in parallel), not 512x512-bit multiply.  And SIMD multiply is only single-uop for floating-point or for 52-bit integers per 64-bit element (AVX512-IFMA52 extension), except on Zen4 where even `vpmullq` is single-uop (per 256-bit lane) same as the IFMA512 insns, unlike on Intel.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple binary division algorithm using `_ExtInt(256)`:

I assume you are writing something related to ethereum so I'll also attach the exp mod function below:

```
; typedef _ExtInt(256) I;
; void udiv256(I n, I d, I* q) {
;     *q = 0;
;     while (n >= d) {
;         I i = 0, d_t = d;
;         while (n >= (d_t << 1) && ++i)
;             d_t <<= 1;
;         *q |= (I)1 << i;
;         n -= d_t;
;     }
; }
define dso_local void @udiv256(i256*, i256*, i256*) {
  store i256 0, i256* %2, align 8
  %4 = load i256, i256* %0, align 8
  %5 = load i256, i256* %1, align 8
  %6 = icmp slt i256 %4, %5
  br i1 %6, label %24, label %7

  %8 = phi i256 [ %22, %16 ], [ %5, %3 ]
  %9 = phi i256 [ %21, %16 ], [ %4, %3 ]
  br label %10

  %11 = phi i256 [ %15, %10 ], [ 0, %7 ]
  %12 = phi i256 [ %13, %10 ], [ %8, %7 ]
  %13 = shl i256 %12, 1
  %14 = icmp slt i256 %9, %13
  %15 = add nuw nsw i256 %11, 1
  br i1 %14, label %16, label %10

  %17 = shl nuw i256 1, %11
  %18 = load i256, i256* %2, align 8
  %19 = or i256 %18, %17
  store i256 %19, i256* %2, align 8
  %20 = load i256, i256* %0, align 8
  %21 = sub nsw i256 %20, %12
  store i256 %21, i256* %0, align 8
  %22 = load i256, i256* %1, align 8
  %23 = icmp slt i256 %21, %22
  br i1 %23, label %24, label %7

  ret void
}


; void sdiv256(I* n, I* d, I* q) {
;     I ret = (I)1;
;     if (*n < (I)0) { ret *= (I)-1; *n = -*n; }
;     if (*d < (I)0) { ret *= (I)-1; *d = -*d; }
;     udiv256(n, d, q);
;     *q *= ret;
; }
define dso_local void @sdiv256(i256*,i256*, i256*) {
  %4 = load i256, i256* %0, align 8
  %5 = icmp slt i256 %4, 0
  br i1 %5, label %6, label %8

  %7 = sub nsw i256 0, %4
  store i256 %7, i256* %0, align 8
  br label %8

  %9 = phi i256 [ -1, %6 ], [ 1, %3 ]
  %10 = load i256, i256* %1, align 8
  %11 = icmp slt i256 %10, 0
  br i1 %11, label %12, label %15

  %13 = sub nsw i256 0, %9
  %14 = sub nsw i256 0, %10
  store i256 %14, i256* %1, align 8
  br label %15

  %16 = phi i256 [ %13, %12 ], [ %9, %8 ]
  store i256 0, i256* %2, align 8
  %17 = load i256, i256* %0, align 8
  %18 = load i256, i256* %1, align 8
  %19 = icmp slt i256 %17, %18
  br i1 %19, label %39, label %20

  %21 = phi i256 [ %35, %29 ], [ %18, %15 ]
  %22 = phi i256 [ %34, %29 ], [ %17, %15 ]
  br label %23

  %24 = phi i256 [ %28, %23 ], [ 0, %20 ]
  %25 = phi i256 [ %26, %23 ], [ %21, %20 ]
  %26 = shl i256 %25, 1
  %27 = icmp slt i256 %22, %26
  %28 = add nuw nsw i256 %24, 1
  br i1 %27, label %29, label %23

  %30 = shl nuw i256 1, %24
  %31 = load i256, i256* %2, align 8
  %32 = or i256 %31, %30
  store i256 %32, i256* %2, align 8
  %33 = load i256, i256* %0, align 8
  %34 = sub nsw i256 %33, %25
  store i256 %34, i256* %0, align 8
  %35 = load i256, i256* %1, align 8
  %36 = icmp slt i256 %34, %35
  br i1 %36, label %37, label %20

  %38 = load i256, i256* %2, align 8
  br label %39

  %40 = phi i256 [ %38, %37 ], [ 0, %15 ]
  %41 = mul nsw i256 %40, %16
  store i256 %41, i256* %2, align 8
  ret void
}


; void neg(I* n) {
;     *n = -*n;
; }
define dso_local void @neg(i256*) {
  %2 = load i256, i256* %0, align 8
  %3 = sub nsw i256 0, %2
  store i256 %3, i256* %0, align 8
  ret void
}

; void modPow(I* b, I* e, I* ret) {
;     *ret = (I)1;
;     I p = *b;
;     for (I n = *e; n > (I)0; n >>= 1) {
;         if ((n & (I)1) != (I)0)
;             *ret *= p;
;         p *= p;
;     }
; }
define dso_local void @powmod(i256*, i256* ,i256*) {
  store i256 1, i256* %2, align 8
  %4 = load i256, i256* %1, align 8
  %5 = icmp sgt i256 %4, 0
  br i1 %5, label %6, label %8

  %7 = load i256, i256* %0, align 8
  br label %9

  ret void

  %10 = phi i256 [ %18, %17 ], [ 1, %6 ]
  %11 = phi i256 [ %20, %17 ], [ %4, %6 ]
  %12 = phi i256 [ %19, %17 ], [ %7, %6 ]
  %13 = and i256 %11, 1
  %14 = icmp eq i256 %13, 0
  br i1 %14, label %17, label %15

  %16 = mul nsw i256 %10, %12
  store i256 %16, i256* %2, align 8
  br label %17

  %18 = phi i256 [ %10, %9 ], [ %16, %15 ]
  %19 = mul nsw i256 %12, %12
  %20 = lshr i256 %11, 1
  %21 = icmp eq i256 %20, 0
  br i1 %21, label %8, label %9
}
```